# Pipling STDOUT to script not activating script

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am trying to pipe the stdout from a script to a bash script that sends a curl POST with the info.

This is what the command looks like:

```
rtl_fm -g 100 -d 3 -s 22050 -f ${pager_freq} - | multimon-ng -q -f alpha -a POCSAG512 -t raw - | tee page-upload.sh
```

When I simply echo to the script the text that is similar to the output the script works as expected:

```
echo "POCSAG512: Address: 1210001  Function: 0  Alpha:   P121 TO REPLACE UNIT P116<LF>IN STATION 116<LF>6825 TOMKEN RD<LF>2017/09/11  17:23:50<EOT>"|page-upload.sh
```

I have tried doing the curl directly after the echo or inside bash scripts and even php, but for some reason no joy.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You using `tee` the wrong way. `tee` writes to a file, it does not call a script. Maybe you mean something like this

```
rtl_fm -g 100 -d 3 -s 22050 -f ${pager_freq} - | multimon-ng -q -f alpha -a POCSAG512 -t raw - | tee upload.log | page-upload.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried it with and without the tee. The tee was there to echo to the shell so I could see when something was being sent to the script, and it did that.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out that the problem was related to how the multimon-ng app was outputting stdout. Without getting into the weeds, here is how I fixed it in my bash script by inserting a while statement:

while read message
do
  curl https://www.example.com/text_reciever.php -X POST --data-urlencode "$message"
done